# How can I isolate text inputs/textareas/contenteditable divs from one another for purposes of 'undo' in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, undo-redo

Unfortunately, I know that the proposed undomanager standard is a long way off. Is there an existing technique or library for isolating individual elements that can receive text input, so that each will maintain its own undo/redo stack **in Chrome**?

For example, if I have a comment box and a search box on a page, repeatedly hitting ctrl+z (or 'undo' in the context menu) will undo typing in both inputs. I'd like to emulate Firefox's functionality and keep undo/redo for these inputs separate.